# How can I convert from this 24615478158188 uid code to this f69a4e9e uid code from ESP-RFID?

Tags: python-3.x, rfid

We have a UID code like this 24615478158188 but ESP-RFID can only read like this f69a4e9e. So how can I convert it in python? Thanks.

Comment: What is `24615478158188`? And what is `f69a4e9e`? How are they related/converted into each other? If you want to convert decimal to hexadecimal you may use `heaxdecimal = hex(decimal)`. Values in the question give the following results: `hex(24615478158188)` is `16633cd4e36c`, `int('f69a4e9e', 16)` is `4137307806`.

Comment: https://github.com/esprfid/esp-rfid/
We are currently using this firmware for a recent project.

Previously we have more than 2000 students which their ID numbers were already collected. and we used this code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NF_oAyY45KgujWqu1r492LRYJK1lxrec/view?usp=sharing

The problem is, we tried scanning an rfid and the output of the esp-rfid firmware which I stated above is f69a4e9e, using the stated code, the output is 24615478158188

Note that 24615478158188 and f69a4e9e is the same rfid card.

Comment: There is no general solution to the problem. Ways to get a value (ID) based on some set of values are innumerable. To try to solve the problem you should know how exactly IDs are generated in both cases to perform convertion old-to-new. This approach may work and may not.

Comment: Thanks for your response